# How to partition a Hive Table using range of values for a column

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-partitions, hiveddl

I have a Hive Table with 2 columns.Employee ID and Salary.

Data is something like given below.

```
Employee ID Salary
1   10000.08
2   20078.67
3   20056.45
4   30000.76
5   10045.14
6   43567.76
```

I want to create Partitions based on Salary Column.For Example Partition for salary range 10000 to 20000, 20001 to 30000.

How do i achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hive does not support range partitioning, but you can calculate ranges during data load.

1. Create table partitioned by salary_range:

   ```
   create table your_table
   (
    employee_id bigint,
    salary double
   )
   partitioned by (salary_range bigint)
   ```
2. insert using case for salary range calculation:

   ```
   insert overwrite table your_table partition (salary_range)   
   select employee_id, salary,  
          case 
              when salary between 10000 and 20000 then 20000
              when salary between 20001 and 30000 then 30000 
              ...
              else ...
          end as salary_range 
   from some_table;
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much.I tried the above approach and it's working.